# Is Console.ReadKey(); fine for an azure webjob

Tags: azure, servicestack, azure-webjobs

At the risk of asking a stupid simple question:

I have a console application that uses servicestack framework to listen to a redis queue.  Eventually I want to publish it up as a continuous azure web job.

I've seen examples that use:

```
host.RunAndBlock();
```

However I have no absolutely zero need to use the azure webjobs SDK and so just wondering is there anything **'wrong'** with just using:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

To keep the console program running.

Comment: ...Naturally before the ReadKey() the framework I am using will have started it's redis queue listening on a different thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a **continuous** WebJob.

I don't think `Console.ReadKey()` will work. The call is likely to just blow up in the sandbox that WebJobs run in.

If you are able to do the redis queue listening on the main thread, that would be simplest.

If now, just use an infinite sleep loop in your main. e.g.

`for (;;)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }`

Comment: I don't think I can control the redis queue listening, I've added servicestack  tag to the question to see if other's answer, otherwise I'll mark as accepted for the simple workaround.